# Are the two LTL properties $GF(\psi_1 \land F\psi_2 )$ and $GF(\psi_2 \land F\psi_1 )$ equivalent?

Tags: logic, formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic

Is $GF(\psi_1 \land F\psi_2 )$ equivalent to the property $GF(\psi_2 \land F\psi_1 )$?

Attempt:

In the first property each state must eventually see $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, in the second property as well each state must eventually see $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, as such the two properties must be equivalent. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but you should prove it.  Here's a proof sketch:

*Proof setup:*

> Suppose that $GF(\psi_1 \land F\psi_2)$ is true and assume towards a contradiction that $\neg GF(F\psi_1 \land \psi_2)$.

*Observations:*

> Then there exists a state $s_1$ in which $\neg F(F\psi_1 \land \psi_2)$, which means that every state $s_2 > s_1$ has $\neg(F\psi_1 \land \psi_2)$, which means that for every state $s_2$, either $\neg F\psi_1$ or $\neg \psi_2$.

*Contradiction:*

> But since $GF(\psi_1 \land F\psi_2)$, there exists a state $s_3 > s_2$ such that $s_3 \vDash \psi_1$ and a state $s_3 > s_2'$ such that $s_3' \vDash \psi_2$, which is a contradiction.

The other direction is identical.